# Two Similar CSS files in a website

Tags: php, css

I have one css file(reset.css) in my main page say index.php.

Inside index.php, I am loading another php page(secondary.php). Now the css in reset.css is not getting applied on secondary.php (Now sure why this is happening.)

I have two Questions here :

1.) Why secondry.php is not taking the reset.css styles.
2.) To resolve the issue, Is it OK for me to place another but similar reset.css file in secondary.php ?

Any help will be highly useful.

Code for Including secondary.php

```
$("#tab2_load").load('seconday.php');
```

Comment: um what????????????

Comment: @nogad Whats so weird in my question ?

Comment: do you know the difference between client and server-side?

Comment: show your code for including secondary.php

Comment: @nogad : Yes Off course. Did you understand my question ?

Comment: @Deva At first you said you are including `secondary.php` within php. When you load other files by JS(more specifically with `.load`), you will need to refresh your css files by JS.

Comment: and now your using jquery, sigh

Comment: @AniketSahrawat : Ohh. so how could I refresh it with JS ? Can you assist ?

Comment: @nogad : Buddy I am not much experienced in web devlopment so if I am doing anything wrong, It would be great if you can share your findings

Comment: hang on i will post it to answer field

Comment: Why do I see `secondary.php`, `secondry.php`, and `'seconday.php'`?

Answer (score 1):

First, add an id to your style tags like so:

```
<link id="someID" rel="stylesheet" href="refresh.css" />
```

Next, in Javascript add the following function:

```
function reloadStyle(s){
    $('#someID').attr('href',s);
}
```

Now after this line `$("#tab2_load").load('seconday.php');` call the function `reloadStyle()`

```
reloadStyle( 'refresh.css?v='+Math.random(0,100) );
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mate. you Rock buddy :)